# Didn't get an answer on Math.SE. How to ask at MathOverflow?

Tags: support, migration

A week ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/579062/61691) and all I got was a lousy Tumbleweed badge. In the hope to still get some help (and that the question is not too low-level), I would like to give it a try and ask the question on MathOverflow. Can I simply repost it there? Or should the question be migrated? How is it done? Will a migration affect the tumbleweed badge? (Lousy or not, now that I got it I really want to keep it...)

**EDIT**
In the meanwhile, Daniel Fischer gave a very nice answer. It turned out that my question certainly wasn't "research level", so I'm glad that I finally got an answer here and the question did not end up on MathOverflow.

Comment: Migration will not affect the Tumbleweed badge.  In general, regular (non-tag) badges are virtually never lost (the main exception being if there is some indication of gaming the system to gain badges, such as having numerous sock-puppets upvoting your posts in order to gain the Legendary badge, but you'd likely be stopped well before this point).

Comment: I have a feeling that your question is going to get an uptick in views because of this thread, so perhaps I'll hold of on the migration for a day or two, just to see if something falls out _here_ instead of _there_.  (In general, flagging the question and using a custom note requesting migration would be the usual course of action.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Thanks for your explanation. You are right, my whining on meta already gave 18 extra views to the question within a few hours (before that only 23 views within 7 days). So ok, let's wait a bit.

Comment: I'm not sure it would be well received at  MO... a bounty could be a better course of action than migration. So far I noticed that at least one prominent mathematician from MO, when dropping by MSE, pays attention to the featured tab. (Easy way to find non-routine questions.)

Comment: I salute you on earning the Tumbleweed Badge, which I learned about only after earning one!

Comment: @ArthurFischer Can you tag this as [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't really see anything that should require this tagged as [meta:status-completed].  Perhaps _you_ could add an answer to the effect of the question has a suitable answer now, so there is no need to ask it elsewhere.  (I'm sure it'll also be accepted.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer I wasn't really being serious, just made a feeble joke, as it's not the type of question [feature request] that rightfully gets that tag. As for answering, I don't know what I could write. If you know something, go ahead, earn some meta badges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the discussion in comments, nobody volunteered to write  an answer. So here goes some general advice for avoiding Tumbleweed:

1. Use at least one tag that describes a  broad area of mathematics, because those are the tags that people are likely to have in favorites. E.g., if your question is about C*-algebras, use [functional-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis) in addition to  [c-star-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c-star-algebras). If it's about elliptic functions, use [complex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-analysis) in addition to [elliptic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elliptic-functions). This is similar to MathOverflow practice of putting an ArXiv subject area tag on most questions.
2. If two-three days pass without any activity on the question, add a bounty. Yes, the featured list is long, but it's still manageable, especially when filtered by tags.  Bounties significantly raise the likelihood of an answer, and the cost is offset by extra upvotes to the question.

---

Pipe dream: now that the sidebar of every SE site shows "Hot Network Questions", MO and MSE should strike a deal where instead of SE randomness, MO sidebar will show  unanswered MSE questions with a bounty. I'm sure they would be more appropriate there than what MO gets now:

[image]

Comment: Instead, MO used their contract to get rid of hot questions entirely. Oh well.